# What Visual C++ preprocessor macro is defined based on subsystem selection

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Is there a preprocessor macro that gets defined based on the value of Properties->Linker->System-> Subsystem, so that code can be compiled conditionally such as:

```
#ifdef _WHAT_GOES_HERE_
int WinMain()
#else
int main()
#endif
```

for windows or console.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a [predefined macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros) for this. The subsystem is a linker option, not a compiler one.

Comment: Sad.. I wanted to do this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [/SUBSYSTEM option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2019) specifies the environment for the executable.The choice of subsystem affects the entry point symbol (or entry point function) that the linker will select.

There are no preprocessor macros, only [Predefined macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019) and [Preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/preprocessor-directives?view=vs-2019)